# Android TextView Slow Using append() Hundreds of Times - Solution?

Tags: android, textview, append, line

I have a source code editor for Android, and I have a line numbers counter that's to the left of the main EditText with source code inside it.

I have the following function I use for updating the line numbers text view:

```
String lineDelimiter = "\n";
public void updateLineNumbers(){
    int lines = textBox.getLineCount();
    lineNums.setText(1 + lineDelimiter);
    for(int i = 2; i < lines; i++){
      lineNums.append(i + lineDelimiter);
    }
}
```

All this is fine, but the problem is when you have a document with say 200 odd lines you start to notice a little delay when adding lines. Is this cause Android TextView's setText/append methods are a little slow? Or is it the concatination that's causing the delay?

I've also made a similar function that appends a line number when the user adds a line number, and vice versa, as opposed to clearing the TextView and adding each line numbers again like the function above does. But this function still lags the app when the user adds/removes line(s).

How can I stop this? I can't think of what to do and it's stressing me out because it's lagging my app and rendering it unusable for large files! :(

Thanks for looking!

---

**SOLUTION**

I've found a way to have fast line numbers, which is to use a custom TextView with onDraw(Canvas canvas) overriden and to draw them that way which results in lag-free line numbers :).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this cause Android TextView's setText/append methods are a little slow? Or is it the concatination that's causing the delay?

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and find out.

Off the cuff, I would imagine that calling `append()` a whole bunch of times on a `TextView` will be vastly slower than calling `append()` a bunch of times on a `StringBuilder`, then calling `setText()` once on the `TextView`.

> How can I stop this?

Don't handle line numbers that way. For example, put a `TextView` to the left of the `EditText`, and put your line numbers in the `TextView`, one per line.

Comment: I'd forgot to mention I also tried using a StringBuilder the way you described, it was faster but still lagging. I've kind of found a solution, using a TextView with onDraw() overriden and drawing the line numbers that way is perfect, no lag so far, just have to try and get the layout like I want it. Thanks anyway Mark! :)